# Why do I get "Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]." even though I have it?

Tags: java

I'm getting "Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]." even though I have "public static void main(String args[])" as part of my code
using Dr. Java

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    // just for testing purposes
    int myArray[] = {4,6,8,1,3,2,9,5,7,6,4,2,1,3,9,8,7,5};
    mergeSort(myArray);
    System.out.println("Sorted array is:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(myArray[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

There is code above this, I have no errors but when I try to run the code I get that error.
Thanks in advance.

Below is the code aside from the object class

```
class MergeSortNonRecursive {

    static Stack<ProgramFrame> callStack;

    // this implement the merge algorithm seen in class. Feel free to call it.
    public static void merge(int A[], int start, int mid, int stop) {
        int index1 = start;
        int index2 = mid + 1;
        int tmp[] = new int[A.length];
        int indexTmp = start;

        while (indexTmp <= stop) {
            if (index1 <= mid && (index2 > stop || A[index1] <= A[index2])) {
                tmp[indexTmp] = A[index1];
                index1++;
            } else {
                if (index2 <= stop && (index1 > mid || A[index2] <= A[index1])) {
                    tmp[indexTmp] = A[index2];
                    index2++;
                }
            }
            indexTmp++;
        }
        for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++) A[i] = tmp[i];
    }

    static void mergeSort(int A[]) {
        /* WRITE YOUR CODE HERE */
        //stack we use
        callStack = new Stack<ProgramFrame>();

        //initial program frame
        ProgramFrame current = new ProgramFrame(0, A.length - 1, 1);

        //put frame on stack
        callStack.push(current);

        //as long as our stack isn't empty...
        while (!callStack.empty()) {

            //as long as the top Frame contains more than one integer
            while (callStack.peek().start < callStack.peek().stop) {

                //must be defined before pushing or else the values mess up
                int left = callStack.peek().start;
                int middle = (callStack.peek().start + callStack.peek().stop) / 2;
                int right = callStack.peek().stop;

                current = new ProgramFrame(middle + 1, right, callStack.peek().PC++);
                callStack.push(current);
                //order ensures left is always on the top
                current = new ProgramFrame(left, middle, callStack.peek().PC++);
                callStack.push(current);
            }
            int PC = callStack.peek().PC; // need to check PC's
            int start = callStack.peek().start;  //assign start and mid for merge
            int mid = callStack.peek().stop; //assign left and middle for merge from the left frame
            callStack.pop();

            //required if the next Frame (the right frame) isn't at its base of 1 integer and they have to be the same PC otherwise this will run continously
            if ((callStack.peek().start != callStack.peek().stop) && (PC == callStack.peek().PC)) {

                //must be defined before pushing or else the values mess up
                int left = callStack.peek().start;
                int middle = (callStack.peek().start + callStack.peek().stop) / 2;
                int right = callStack.peek().stop;

                current = new ProgramFrame(middle + 1, right, callStack.peek().PC++);
                callStack.push(current);
                //order ensures left is always on the top
                current = new ProgramFrame(left, middle, callStack.peek().PC++);
                callStack.push(current);
            }

            int stop = callStack.peek().stop; //get stop from the right frame

            merge(A, start, mid, stop); //merge 
        }
    }

    //Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]. ??!??
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        // just for testing purposes
        int myArray[] = {4,6,8,1,3,2,9,5,7,6,4,2,1,3,9,8,7,5};
        mergeSort(myArray);
        System.out.println("Sorted array is:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(myArray[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The entire code would be the following and my file is saved as MergeSortNonRecursive.java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class ProgramFrame {
    int start;
    int stop;
    int PC;

    public ProgramFrame(int myStart, int myStop, int myPC) {
        start = myStart;
        stop = myStop;
        PC = myPC;
    }

    // returns a String describing the content of the object
    public String toString() {
        return "ProgramFrame: start = " + start + " stop = " + stop + " PC = " + PC;
    }
}

class MergeSortNonRecursive {

    static Stack<ProgramFrame> callStack;

    // this implement the merge algorithm seen in class. Feel free to call it.
    public static void merge(int A[], int start, int mid, int stop) {
        int index1 = start;
        int index2 = mid + 1;
        int tmp[] = new int[A.length];
        int indexTmp = start;

        while (indexTmp <= stop) {
            if (index1 <= mid && (index2 > stop || A[index1] <= A[index2])) {
                tmp[indexTmp] = A[index1];
                index1++;
            } else {
                if (index2 <= stop && (index1 > mid || A[index2] <= A[index1])) {
                    tmp[indexTmp] = A[index2];
                    index2++;
                }
            }
            indexTmp++;
        }
        for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++) A[i] = tmp[i];
    }

    static void mergeSort(int A[]) {
        /* WRITE YOUR CODE HERE */
        //stack we use
        callStack = new Stack<ProgramFrame>();

        //initial program frame
        ProgramFrame current = new ProgramFrame(0, A.length - 1, 1);

        //put frame on stack
        callStack.push(current);

        //as long as our stack isn't empty...
        while (!callStack.empty()) {

            //as long as the top Frame contains more than one integer
            while (callStack.peek().start < callStack.peek().stop) {

                //must be defined before pushing or else the values mess up
                int left = callStack.peek().start;
                int middle = (callStack.peek().start + callStack.peek().stop) / 2;
                int right = callStack.peek().stop;

                current = new ProgramFrame(middle + 1, right, callStack.peek().PC++);
                callStack.push(current);
                //order ensures left is always on the top
                current = new ProgramFrame(left, middle, callStack.peek().PC++);
                callStack.push(current);
            }
            int PC = callStack.peek().PC; // need to check PC's
            int start = callStack.peek().start;  //assign start and mid for merge
            int mid = callStack.peek().stop; //assign left and middle for merge from the left frame
            callStack.pop();

            //required if the next Frame (the right frame) isn't at its base of 1 integer and they have to be the same PC otherwise this will run continously
            if ((callStack.peek().start != callStack.peek().stop) && (PC == callStack.peek().PC)) {

                //must be defined before pushing or else the values mess up
                int left = callStack.peek().start;
                int middle = (callStack.peek().start + callStack.peek().stop) / 2;
                int right = callStack.peek().stop;

                current = new ProgramFrame(middle + 1, right, callStack.peek().PC++);
                callStack.push(current);
                //order ensures left is always on the top
                current = new ProgramFrame(left, middle, callStack.peek().PC++);
                callStack.push(current);
            }

            int stop = callStack.peek().stop; //get stop from the right frame

            merge(A, start, mid, stop); //merge 
        }
    }

    //Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]. ??!??
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        // just for testing purposes
        int myArray[] = {4,6,8,1,3,2,9,5,7,6,4,2,1,3,9,8,7,5};
        mergeSort(myArray);
        System.out.println("Sorted array is:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(myArray[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling the right class?

Comment: Yes, its all in the same class. I was building on codes given by my professor. This part was already written out and I haven't changed anything from it and no one in my class seems to be having this problem.

Comment: Make sure it's not in an inner class.

Comment: Show us the class header, etc.

Comment: Please show us the entire file, not just this section of it.  The error isn't in the part that you've shown.

Comment: I have edited to post to contain the entire code, the only area I have touched is the mergeSort method

Comment: How are you running the code? I copy-pasted your full version into a file called MergeSortNonRecursive.java, compiled it with `javac MergeSortNonRecursive.java` and ran it with `java MergeSortNonRecursive` and it worked fine.

Comment: `main` is in class MergeSortNonRecursive.  Not only is this not a public class, but it's not the first class, and likely your .java file is not called MergeSortNonRecursive.java.  What `java` command have you been using to try to execute the class??

Comment: That's unreal. I'm using Dr.Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MergeSortNonRecursive
```

needs to be:

```
public class MergeSortNonRecursive
```

The class containing the main method must be public.

*Update: Tried this in Dr Java*
It looks like Dr Java is trying to run ProgramFrame. I expect the full output is something like this:

```
Welcome to DrJava.  Working directory is /code
> run ProgramFrame
Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[].
```

Putting the class ProgramFrame after the public class MergeSortNonRecursive makes it work. *However*, you have an issue with your mergesort and it will loop forever. You will need to debug that.

Comment: I have made it public and it still gives the same error.

Comment: And the class is in a file called MergeSortNonRecursive.java?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm confused, I was given the code by my professor and all I touched was the mergeSort method

Comment: Can you paste the first 20 or so lines of the stack trace into your question?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. I'm a novice, this is for my second computer science class

Comment: ok, add to your question how you are running it? From the command line or are you using an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ?

Comment: Dr. Java may have such a rule, but Java doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility (speaking from experience) is that before running your program from Dr. Java, make sure that you have the correct java class file selected on the left column of the screen.  For example, one of my apps consists of three java classes.  If I have the class with the main method in it selected then it works fine.  But if I have a different class in the project selected then I get the error message:  "Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]."  This error makes sense since the selected class doesn't have the main method in it, but I was expecting Dr. Java to look through all classes in the project to find the main method.